# How should i find size in OMNet++?

Tags: omnet++

I need to find packet size sent by each node in OMNeT++. Do i need to set it by myself or is there any way of finding the packet size which is changing dynamically. 
Kindly tell me the procedure of finding the Packet size?

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're trying to say is, where can you find the "inherent" size of a packet, for example of one that has been defined in a .msg file, based on "what's in it".

If I'm right: You can't. And shouldn't really want to. Since everything inside an OMNeT++ simulation is... *simulation*, no matter what the actual contents of a cPacket are, the bitLength property can be set to any value, with no regard to the amount of information stored in your custom messages.

So the only size any packet will have is the size set either by you manually, or by the model library you are using, with the setBitLength() method.

It is useful in scenarios where a protocol header has some fields that are of some weird length, like 3 bits, and then 9 bits, and 1 flag bit, etc. It is best to represent these fields as separate members in the message class, and since C++ doesn't have* these flexible size data types, the representation in the simulation and the represented header will have different sizes.

Or if you want to cheat, and transmit extra information with a packet, that wouldn't really be a part of it on a real network, in the actual bit sequence.

So you should just set the appropriate length with setBitLength, and don't care about what is actually stored. Usually. Until your computer runs out of memory.

I might be completely wrong about what you're trying to get to.

*Yes, there are bit fields, but ... it's easier not having to deal with them.

Comment: i have created a cMssage. In this cMessage i am sending one hop neighbor ids(using getId()) of a node's neighbors in an int vector. Its size is changing when neighbors of that node changes. So i cannot set the packet size. Do i need to calculate packet size by sizeof each element of that vector? and then set it in setBitLength() ?

Comment: Yes, you should calculate and set the size on the packet yourself when it changes. However, I wouldn't recommend using sizeof, as that is not very portable, and easy to use wrong. Rather, calculate how long the packet would be in the actual protocol you're simulating, based on how the node IDs would be stored in the real packet, and use that.

Comment: Thank you Torokati. would you please tell me what should i use instead of sizeof for finding the size of node ids. whose type is int?

Comment: Just think of how you would serialize your packet, including the node IDs, to be used on a real network. All fields would have a given length there, something like 2 or 4 bytes per node ID, plus the rest.

Comment: i could not understand you. When i do sizeof(getId()), it returns 4 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about `cPakets` in OMNeT++, then simply use the according getter methods for the length of a packet. That is for cases where the packets have a real size set either by you or in your code.

From the `cpacket.h` in the OMNeT 5.1 release:

```
/**
 * Returns the packet length (in bits).
 */
virtual int64_t getBitLength() const  {return bitLength;}

/**
 * Returns the packet length in bytes, that is, bitlength/8. If bitlength
 * is not a multiple of 8, the result is rounded up.
 */
int64_t getByteLength() const  {return (getBitLength()+7)>>3;}
```

So simply read the value, maybe write it into a temporary variable and use it for whatever you need it.